# MySQL avoiding subquery to find all rows with the same value in a column

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm trying to do the following query to find rows that have 5 other rows with the same value in a specific column:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE columnName IN (
   SELECT columnName FROM `tbl` GROUP BY columnName HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
)
```

The query seems to take forever and I needed to kill it manually. However, the subquery by itself is very fast. The reason I want the whole rows because I'm planning to delete these rows. I know sub-queries can become super slow at times, and it's best to avoid them.

How can I write the same without using a subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a temporary table as approach to fast execution:

```
-- creating indexed temporary results

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `tmp_tbl`;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp_tbl`
   SELECT columnName FROM `tbl` GROUP BY columnName HAVING COUNT(*) > 5;

CREATE INDEX icolname ON  `tmp_tbl`(columnName);

-- now selecting your data
SELECT `tbl`.* 
FROM `tbl` INNER JOIN `tmp_tbl` on `tbl`.columnName = `tmp_tbl`.columnName;

-- to delete your data
DELETE FROM `tbl` 
INNER JOIN `tmp_tbl` on `tbl`.columnName = `tmp_tbl`.columnName;
```

I tested in a table with 100000+ records, it runs in 2-4 secs against 50+ secs with subquery.

Comment: Worked great. I actually needed to delete these rows so just changed the ending query to a `DELETE FROM tbl WHERE columnName IN (SELECT columnName FROM tmp_tbl)` which made me again use a sub-query, but in this case it worked fast. Do you have an explanation on WHY this isn't how the original query is executed?

Comment: I added a delete query using the temp table without subqueries.